# wp-cli silently fails with error code 255

Tags: plugins

When I run most wp-cli commands I get silent failure. If I echo the return code, I can see that it is 255.

Some background. Our team is working on a plugin. Previous version of plugin works fine with wp-cli. If I update the plugin ($ wp plugin update our-plugin) the plugin updates, and the site seems to work fine, BUT, any further commands with wp-cli fail with return code 255.

I am talking about simple commands like ($ wp plugin list) or ($ wp plugin status)
The 255 error codes even extend to theme subcommands as well.

The question is: How do I debug this? Is there a way to get more details failure information from wp-cli?

Thanks,
John Schank

Comment: This might be worth reporting as possible issue to wp-cli issue tracker on github.

Comment: @Rarst: yeah, I agree. I just wanted to do some due diligence and make sure we aren't doing something to cause this.

Comment: Well, you very well might, but it doesn't sound like anything I ever heard so the more specific wp-cli expertise is probably in order. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could at least try to run `wp COMMAND --debug` to see what this will give you.

I once got this after I manually copied a preprocessed `wp-config.php` in place to be used inside a Docker container. Suddenly all commands stopped working, silently. The container returned me a `255`. With `--debug` I could identify at which point exactly the commands stopped working and identified that it must have been the `wp-config.php`.

In the end I fixed it by generating the config with `wp config create` and suddenly WP-CLI started working again. Would be interesting to know if your error disappears as soon as you remove your `wp-config.php`. WP-CLI then should tell you that there's no config existent and might suggest using `wp config create` to create one.